# How to write gunits for form inference classes

Tags: guidewire

While trying to write gunits for form inference classes, getting the below error while setting the context. How can I achieve it?

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Please share the code as a snippet and not a screenshot when asking questions. Stack Overflow enforces that questions with code in screenshots are downvoted/flagged as needing improvement.

Answer (score 1):

There's a compilation error since the constructor is protected and not intended to be used outside the `forms` package or a subclass. I don't think you need to initialize `FormInferenceContext` by calling the constructor. How about quoting or issuing the submission with the appropriate availability conditions and then checking the existence of the form using something like

```
policyPeriod.Forms.hasMatch(\f -> f.FormPatternCode == "ABCD")
```

You can then write an assert on whether the form is found (available) or not. Reproducing or mimicking what happens in `FormInferenceEngine` is not required for GUnits.